# meaning of the phrase 'thematically consistent'

Tags: meaning, phrases

> It's *thematically consistent*. Every game is rigged.

I understand what the term rigged means and also know meanings of the terms thematically and consistent, however are not sure of what exactly it means put together.

Comment: It means the rigging in the game is good. There are no mistakes in it as the rigging is consistent in terms of its themes.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to give us the text that surrounds this sentence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know you said you know what the words mean individually, but they have multiple definitions so I'll cover them anyway.

A 'theme' might be described as a recurrent idea that creates coherence throughout an entire experience. For example, in a story, a theme might tie chapters together.

'Thematically consistent' would therefore mean that several things being compared have the same theme, or are 'consistent' with their theme.

'Consistency' is when several things, perhaps related things or in a sequence like chapters of a story, are clearly related either by sharing a common theme or by harmonising in some other way.

Your quotation mentions "games" being "rigged". I would suggest that the games are the things being compared and being "rigged" is what they have in common. "Thematically consistent" seems to mean that the consistent rigging is actually a 'theme' of the games.